# I can't fix the "argumentoutofrangeexception was unhandled"

Tags: vba

I'm trying to develop an app on visual Basic. That calculates the restaurant bill by taking the price in one text and the quantity in the other textbook.It then adds the values to two individual `listboxes`. It then multiplies the values in the two `listboxes` and adds them.

I managed to get the code right and tried it a few times but then it gave me the

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

PS: It's an introduction course so I'm pretty dense about the whole thing

Here's the coding I used

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim q As Integer
    Dim p As Double
    Dim sum As Double = 0
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim result As Double


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        p = Val(TextBox3.Text)
        q = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(q)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)
        ListBox3.Items.Add(p)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click   

        Do
            result = ListBox1.Items.Item(q) * ListBox3.Items.Item(p) 'this is where the error occurs
            n += 1
            sum += result
        Loop Until n = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Label8.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", sum)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What line is it stopping at?

Answer (score 0):

If you Enter anything new in your TextBoxes and then Press `Button2` before `Button1` you are trying to Access a Value which didnt got added to your List yet. So you are getting an out of Range Exception.